# ¿Porque solo obtengo null de getPhotoUrl de un objeto FirebaseUser?

Tags: android, firebase, autenticación, nullpointerexception

Este es el codigo donde estoy usando el objeto de tipo FirebaseUser

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
Toast.makeText(Login.this,"Bienvenido: "+user.getPhotoUrl().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Navigation.class);
intent.putExtra(Navigation.users,user.getDisplayName());
intent.putExtra(Navigation.correos,user.getEmail());
intent.putExtra(Navigation.urlsPerfil,user.getPhotoUrl().toString());
startActivity(intent);
```

Este es el error que me lanza

```
 Process: com.fundamentos.tomy.helpmyfido, PID: 5959
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.net.Uri.toString()' on a null object reference
    at com.fundamentos.tomy.helpmyfido.Login$2$1.onComplete(Login.java:92)
    at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzj.run(Unknown Source)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5422)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:914)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:707)
```

Estoy usando los metodos que vi en la documentación de Firebase, pero solo tengo este error cuando los implemento

Comment: getPhotoUrl() te esta devolviendo null porque no tiene foto de autentificacion el usuario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si utilizas un proveedor como Gmail para registrar o loguear un usuario, el proveedor si te da el nombre del usuario y la foto , pero si el login es con Firebase directamente con email y password no vas a tener disponible con `FirebaseUser` esas opciones , para eso vas a tener que hacer uso de `UserProfileChangeRequest` , entonces cuando registres un usuario vas a tener que hacer que tome o elija una foto para crear ese usuario con una foto ya asignada , y luego setear esa información para poder usarla con `FirebaseUser`

Por ejemplo para setear `getDisplayName` y `getPhotoUrl` , esto lo haces en la ventana de registro

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
        .setDisplayName("Jane Q. User")
        .setPhotoUri(Uri.parse("https://example.com/jane-q-user/profile.jpg"))
        .build();

user.updateProfile(profileUpdates)
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "User profile updated.");
                }
            }
        });
```

Te dejo el link para que veas 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users?hl=es-419

Luego de hacer ese cambio ya en los próximos login ya podes usar esas opciones sin problemas, ten en cuenta que el mejor lugar para asignar estos datos es la ventana donde registras el usuario. Lo puedes hacer luego del login también, es lo mismo, el null que te tira es por qué no encuentra nada asociado a ese usuario.